# WebRTC connection from desktop to mobile app

Tags: android, ios, webrtc

Can I make a peer to peer connection between a website user (let's say desktop Firefox or Chrome) to a native mobile app on Android and/or iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make a peer connection between a desktop browser and a mobile app. This can be done with the [AppRTCDemo](https://webrtc.org/native-code/) app for mobile and [apprtc](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) for the browser, for example.